# Use break instead of paragraph when pressing enter in wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress

Extremely annoying:
When I am writing a new post in Wordpress (latest version) and I am pressing `<ENTER>`, I get a paragraph break instead of a simple break.
eg:

text `ENTER`

text

instead of

text `ENTER`
text

How do I disable this behavior?
I do NOT want to use `Shift+Enter` to get this desired (_ common sense _) action.

Answer (score 2):

Write your article in HTML tab instead of the Visual tab and you'll not have this problem anymore.

Comment: sure, I tried. After I hit Publish it has exactly the same effect as writing it in Visual.